# $.each looping over JSON data slows down browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to load Json data with value of minimum 4000 records, I'm trying to create option for select tag with the json data. I do it by iterating using $.each. This hang up my browser. Any one provide a solution to handle this.

```
var prevGroup, $group = $();
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
   var group = value.nested;

   if (group != prevGroup) {
       $group = $('<optgroup />', {label: group}).appendTo('#select');
   }

   if (value.selected !== "") {
       $group.append($('<option />', {
         text: value.text,
         value: value.value,
         selected: value.selected,
       }));
    } else {
       $group.append($('<option />', {
          text: value.text,
          value: value.value
        }));
    }

    prevGroup = group;


});
```

Comment: The solution: don't loop over 4000 records. Seriously. Look for a better pattern to retrieve your data, such as paging, to split the data retrieved.

Comment: so you put 4k tag in your markup, its a huge breakfast for your DOM

Comment: for looping over bulk data its better to use `For loop` instead of `$.each()`, also you should pull data with pagination a small amount at a time

Comment: 4000 options in a select provides a poor user experience. Why don't you use auto-complete with validation instead?  Or provide a picker to select that data with pagination as was suggested by Rory.

Comment: Might speed it up: Don't build jquery objects in each iteration (`$('<option>')`) but concatenate a js string (`"<option>...</option><option>...</option>"`) and after `.each` append it to the dom. Each invocation of `$('<option />')` etc. is slow.

Comment: Can you provide your json, or similar, and create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). It'll be much easier to help then.

Comment: Here is working fiddle url http://jsfiddle.net/Boopaathy/qzrnqnwv/

Answer (score 0):

Try this each to see if it is JQuery.

```
each=function(a,b,c){if("function"==typeof b)for(var d=0;d<a.length;d++)b(d,a[d]);else for(var d=0;d<a.length;d++)typeof a[d]==b&&c(d,a[d])};
```

Use as

```
each(array,function(index,value){

    });
```